# Second order Taylor polynomial at x = 0?

Tags: calculus, analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion

What is the complete second order Taylor polynomial?  at x = 0? I have done solving many times but the results were different.

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ and suppose that
> $f : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to (-1, \infty)$ is a $C^2$ function
> which satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and
> $$f(x) + \ln(1 + f(x)) = x.$$
> Calculate the second order Taylor polynomial of $f$ around the point
> $x_0 = 0$

Comment: Hint: differentiate both sides of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. Instead of using images, you should typeset your question so that it's searchable by future users who might have a similar question. I've edited it for you this time, though

Comment: Also, what have you tried? You mention you've done it several times, but you're getting different results. Can you include some of those efforts? Once we have a better of idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: How did you get different results?

Comment: [inverse](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20720/166212) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Second order Taylor polynomial of f is:

$$f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$$

We are evaluating this at $a=0$ so the polynomial becomes the Maclaurin series:

$$f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!}x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2$$

Differentiate both sides of the equation you supplied to find $f'$:
\begin{alignat}{3}
&& \frac{d}{dx} (f(x)+\ln(1+f(x)) & = \frac{d}{dx} (x) \\
\implies && \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{1+f(x)} & = 1 \\
\implies && \frac{df}{dx}\left(1 + \frac{1}{1+f(x)}\right) & = 1 \\
\implies && \frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{1+f(x)}{2+f(x)}
\end{alignat}
Evaluate $f'$ at $x=0$:

$$\frac{df}{dx}(0) = \frac{1+f(0)}{2+f(0)} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Use the quotient rule to solve $f''$:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{df}{dx}) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1+f(x)}{2+f(x)}\right)$$

$$ \implies \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = \frac{ (2+f(x))\frac{df}{dx} - (1+f(x))\frac{df}{dx}}{(2+f(x))^2} = \frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{(2+f(x))^2} = \frac{1+f(x)}{(2+f(x))^3}.$$

Evaluate $f''$ at $x=0$:

$$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(0) = \frac{1+f(0)}{(2+f(0))^3} = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Therefore, the Taylor polynomial can be expressed as follows:

$$f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!}x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{16}x^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

*A small trick*

In a case such this one where $f(x)$ is defined by an implicit equation, you can start from where you want to arrive to that is to say
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \,x^k+O(x^{n+1})$$ (there is no $a_0$ since $f(0)=0$ and replace.

So, the implicit equation you face is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \,x^k+\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \,x^k\right)-x=0\tag 1$$ Using
$$\log(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon-\frac 12 \epsilon^2+\frac 13 \epsilon^3+\cdots$$ we shall make $\epsilon=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \,x^k$ and use the binomial expansion up to the order which is required.

Let us say that we need the third order. So
$$\epsilon=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+O(x^4)$$
$$\epsilon^2=a_1^2 x^2+2 a_1 a_2 x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\epsilon^3=a_1^3 x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and now replace in $(1)$ to have
$$a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\left(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \right)-\frac 12\left( a_1^2 x^2+2 a_1 a_2 x^3\right)+\frac 13\left(a_1^3 x^3\right)-x=0$$ Group the terms of same power
$$(2 a_1-1) x+\left(2 a_2-\frac{a_1^2}{2}\right)
   x^2+\left(\frac{a_1^3}{3}-a_1 a_2+2 a_3\right)x^3=0$$
Cancel the coefficients one at the time to get
$$a_1=\frac 12 \qquad a_2=\frac 1{16} \qquad a_3=-\frac 1{192} $$

So $$f(x)=\frac 12 x+\frac 1{16}x^2-\frac 1{192}x^3+O(x^4)$$